# Creating AleartDialog's setSingleChoiceItems() method from custome ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-alertdialog

I have an **ArrayList** of custom model called **Grade**. This model contain **getName()** method that returns the name of the grade.

My requirements are to

Use this ArrayList's Grade medel's **getName()** method to create Alert Diolog's **setSingleChoiceItems()** by passing **gradeNames** array.

And also I want to get the selected item(Whole Grade model) back when I select on some item on the list that displayed on AlertDialog.

```
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(gradeNames, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

          //**Here I want to get selected item back as "Grade" Object

          notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Please help me to salve this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Use:**

```
  yourArrayList.get(which);
```

inside of `setSingleChoiceItems()`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want to create gradeNames[] using my ArrayList<Grade>, Then pass as it to create singleItemList and, when select on Item, I need to get baack whole Grade object that is in the selected position.

Comment: **Use** `String[] gradeNames = new String[yourArrayList.size()]` to create **gradeNames**. Use a  **for loop** to populate **gradeNames** by calling **getName()** on each **ArrayList** index and placing the result in the corresponding **gradeNames** index. Than use your above `setSingleChoiceItems()` code and `yourArrayList.get(which);` to get the required Grade object.

Comment: Yep. I have already implemented this way. But I'm looking for something that can be done without creating a separate String[]. Do you have any Idea? :)

Comment: One of the implementation of `setSingleChoiceItems()` takes a **ListAdapter** as the first arg. You can maybe try that out.